# I am no longer getting the list of friends who use my app. It was working for a few days, now it has stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the `FB.api` Javascript API to access the list of friends of the current user (`me`) who also use the app:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,friends.fields(installed,name),birthday,gender,location,email', function(res) {...
```

I set it up about a week ago and it was working just fine for all the users. It was getting me a list of all the friends but those who used the app, there was an additional parameter with value set to true (`"installed" : true`)

Now I am seeing that for some mysterious reason this parameter `installed` no longer appears any more! I have made no change in the code. Any idea why is that what is the right way of getting it again??

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, one that Facebook is taking a long time to fix. Please see and repro the issue here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178979062276800?browse=external_tasks_search_results_51d78ad8d6aa07f26501758

As a work-around, you can use the entire friends list and cross-reference every Facebook ID with those in your database to see who is actually using the app.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems that this issue came up just a couple of days ago as the postings were not more than two days old. Hopefully, it will go away soon. I think I will wait rather than changing the code.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. We'll see how things pan out.